# node js XMLHttpRequest issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

Trying to run this in node js, code is constant throwing error on "xhr.target.status" of function makeCORRequest as if its not inheriting XMLHttpRequest functions for xhr. Code is for discord bot trying to get it to post from teamup calendar.
first function is working (and is where xhr is initialised) and is called by error function.

```html
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var apiKey = 'API_KEY';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari/IE10+.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Teamup-Token', apiKey);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        // XDomainRequest for IE8/IE9.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        // XDomainRequest does not support querying HTTPS from HTTP pages
        if (window.location.protocol === 'http:') {
            url = url.replace('https://', 'http://');
        }
        if (-1 === ['GET', 'POST'].indexOf(method)) {
            alert('XDomainRequest only supports GET and POST methods');
            return;
        }
        if (-1 === url.indexOf('?')) {
            url += '?_teamup_token=' + apiKey;
        } else {
            url += '&_teamup_token=' + apiKey;
        }
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        // CORS not supported.
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}
```

And this is the function that keeps failing. What works fine is xhr.onload =function(xhr), but if(xhr.target.status<400) throws the error "cannot read property"

```
// Sends the actual CORS request.
function makeCorsRequest(url, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
    if (!xhr) {
        alert('CORS not supported');
        return;
    }

    // Response handlers.
    xhr.onload = function (xhr) {
        if (xhr.target.status < 400) {
            if (successCallback) successCallback(xhr.target);
        } else if (errorCallback) {
            errorCallback(xhr.target);
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (xhr) {
        if (errorCallback) {
            errorCallback(xhr.target);
        }
    };

    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: If you are running this server side there are better request libraries you could use

Comment: http request I suppose you mean, I guess I have to code that from ground instead of using this snipet then, would issue be then that node js cannot handle xhr even with xmlhttprequest installed?